# Datepicker submit format

Tags: materialize

In the new version of materialize the new 'datepicker' seems to have lost the option for 'formatSubmit'

format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'

You use to be able to display the date in the page in one format and submit it in another.

Anyone have a way round this?

Comment: Now it returns Date object so you can use that object in whichever way you like

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example?

Comment: I think yes, I'm having one or I can create one for you.